# Is the split between Continental and Analytical comparable to the split between Empiricism and Rationalism, if so can it be reconciled?

Tags: kant, analytic-philosophy, continental-philosophy

Just as Kant reconciled empiricism and rationalism, is there a project to unify analytical and continental ?  Or is Analytical philosophy irreversibly ingrained in Scientism while continental philosophy collapses into relativism ?

Comment: What do you think the difference between continental and analytical philosophy is? Other than the obvious stylistic differences, I mean.

Comment: You may also read a similar question https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/7897/has-analytical-or-continental-philosophy-had-the-more-profound-or-greater-impact?rq=1

Comment: Even the names themselves evince how hidebound the promoters of such a distinction are.

Comment: @TankutBeygu I mean yeah us anglophones do believe we're the centre of the world. We do the real philosophy whereas the french have their kooky weird Focault sex philosophy lmao. That's the connotation that comes from the naming lol

Comment: Your question seems to presuppose that there is benefit in unifying them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy answer to this question. The split between Continental and Analytical philosophy is complex, and there is no simple way to reconcile the two traditions. However, it is worth noting that there are efforts being made to bring the two traditions closer together. For example, the Centre for the Study of the History and Philosophy of the Sciences at the University of London hosts Joint Sessions of the Aristotelian Society and the Mind Association, which bring together leading figures from both traditions to discuss common problems and issues. Similarly, the British Society for the History of Philosophy holds an annual conference which includes both Continental and Analytical philosophers.

It is also worth noting that there are significant overlaps between the two traditions. Many Analytical philosophers, such as Gottlob Frege and Bertrand Russell, were deeply influenced by Continental philosophers such as Kant and Hegel. Similarly, many Continental philosophers, such as Martin Heidegger and Jean-Paul Sartre, were deeply influenced by Analytical philosophers such as Ludwig Wittgenstein.

Therefore, while the split between Continental and Analytical philosophy is significant, it is not insurmountable.

Answer (score 1):

The names continential and analytic don't signify any internal differences between the philosophies held by each, like rationalism and empiricism do, but moreso location. Certainly, there are philosophical trends more likely in each, like the relativism and the strong trust in inductive reasoning existing in one or the other accordingly, but usually people want to resolve "splits" in philosophy when the position in each contradicts the other.